# How to use global object in Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a global object in window as "Apollo".

I try to use it in Angular like `Apollo.get()` and as types: `function show(): Apollo.Data {}`.

How to do that?

I have tried to determine:

```
typings.d.ts
```

With content:

```
declare var Apollo;
```

But inside Angular code I can not use it as type:

```
let el:Apollo.Data.
```

And `new Apollo.Geometry();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find out `polyfills.ts` and end of the file place below Snippet.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Apollo: any;
  }
}
```